# Formula for the derivatives in backpropagation for neural networks?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, computer-science, machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm following Andrew Ng's Coursera course on machine learning. In week 5 he introduces backpropagation and the $\delta$ term which is meant to represent the "error" a neuron has.

He gives us this:

[image]

formula, where the .* represents the operation of elementwise multiplication (since the two arguments are both vectors).

He then gives a formula for the $g'(z^{(3)})$ term, which is $a^{(3)}.* (1-a^{(3)})$. He says that it's possible to prove this mathematically, but I'm unable to.

Note that $g(x)$ is the sigmoid function, $1/(1+e^{-x})$, and as such $g'(x) = \frac {e^{-x}}{(1+e^{-x})^2}$. Also note that functions in this course, when applied to vectors or matrices, are assumed to be applied elementwise.

Also note that $z^{(3)}$ = $\Theta^{(3)} a^{(3)}$. $\Theta^{(3)}$ is the matrix of weights for the 3rd layer, and $a^{(3)}$ is the activations of the units in the 3rd layer.

I hope that this is common terminology not just specific to this course, otherwise I guess answering this question is difficult because you don't know what the letters mean. I can't succintly explain the terms further...

Nonetheless, by slightly simplifying $g'(z^{(3)})$ I get: $$\frac {e^{ -\Theta^{(3)} a^{(3)} }} {1 + 2e^{ -\Theta^{(3)} a^{(3)} } + e^{ -2\Theta^{(3)} a^{(3)} } } $$

Is it feasible to get to $a^{(3)}.* (1-a^{(3)})$ from here?

Comment: "I don't know why he doesn't just transpose one of them to achieve the same effect". Because that wouldn't be the same thing as element-wise multiplication?

Comment: @BornaAhmadzade Ahh right, sorry I forgot that the dot product also sums all the answers afterwards while here we're looking to get a vector as the output of our element wise multiplication. Thank you!

Comment: No problem:) Also, I recommend you post this on Coursera’s forum because the users there are much more familiar with the terms and you will get more help there